how to install selenium without proplem
I have tried many codes to extract data from the web. I have stored selenium, chromedriver via pip and other methods, always making sure that the version is compatible with the version, but it always gives me a message (library not found). I tried this in more than one programming language (it is not has to do with the code)
I don't knew what the proplem
Thank you for your cooperation
I don't knew what the proplem

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Make sure the chrome driver version matches with the chrome browser version, and ensure to import that specific chrome driver in your programming language of choice.
You can get the latest chrome driver version here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/. Make sure that this matches with the actual browser version (Chrome_Version).
And you should be good to go with the code below.
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
chromedriver_path = "C:/Users/{USERNAME_HERE}/Downloads/chromedriver-win64_latest/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service = ChromeService(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

